# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse React application

Tags: reactjs, json

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { createContext, useEffect, useReducer } from "react";

const INITIAL_STATE = {
    user: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")) || null,
    loading: false,
    error: null,
};

export const AuthContext = createContext(INITIAL_STATE);

const AuthReducer = (state, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case "LOGIN_START":
            return {
                user: null,
                loading: true,
                error: null,
            };
        case "LOGIN_SUCCESS":
            return {
                user: action.payload,
                loading: false,
                error: null,
            };
        case "LOGIN_FAILURE":
            return {
                user: null,
                loading: false,
                error: action.payload,
            };
        case "LOGOUT":
            return {
                user: null,
                loading: false,
                error: null,
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
};

export const AuthContextProvider = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AuthReducer, INITIAL_STATE);

    useEffect(() => {
        localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(state.user));
    }, [state.user]);

    return (
        <AuthContext.Provider
            value={{
                user: state.user,
                loading: state.loading,
                error: state.error,
                dispatch,
            }}
        >
            {children}
        </AuthContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`localStorage.getItem("user")` is undefined. And because the `|| null` is outside of the JSON.parse, it will try to parse undefined which will throw an error on the first character 'u'.

You should use:
`JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user") ?? null)` and remove the outside `|| null`